# I need 5 cd master ubuntu

Tags: boot

I need 5 CDs of Ubuntu for my Computer Laboratory. In my Computer laboratory need operating System like Ubuntu cause ubuntu very user friendly for user Computer beginner and amazing Display. So please give me 5 Cds!

Comment: Do you have access to a DVD write drive?

Comment: You can download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). It's Free! If your lab' computer have RAM under 4 GB, download the 32 bit one. If you have RAM 4 GB or more, download the 64 bit one. Then you can burn the downloaded ISO in the DVD's.

Comment: Is that your phone number and address at the bottom of your question ??? This is a public site and anyone can see that, not a good idea to give that information out in this way, I will remove it, for your privacy and safety.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy DVD disks directly from Canonical - [click here for more info.](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146)

You can buy a pack of 10 for about $13 USD.

Alternatively, if you have access to a DVD writable drive, you can burn your own disks for free - [click here for more info](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

Download the amd64 desktop iso for most **any** 64 bit system including intel.

Download the i386 desktop iso for most 32 bit systems.

[Click here for official instructions.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

or

[Click here for info on how to install from a USB flash drive instead.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)